# "The system cannot find the specified file" for a different file than what I've specified

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

In my csproj I have

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

and when I run a unit test against a class in that assembly I get

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Any idea why this mismatch?

Comment: Depends on what/how the assembly and/or your unit test implements it. Judging by the error, does your _unit test project_ reference `System.Net.Http.Formatting`? Additional note: It's now part of [`ASP.NET Web API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt174857(v=vs.118).aspx). Hth.

Comment: In NuGet Package Manager is that library listed under `Consolidate`?

Comment: @Questionaire, Have you try to add the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3` to the unit test project?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the exception indicates that the missing version is 5.2.2.0, while you are referencing 5.2.3.0

You might have another dependency that references 5.2.2.0.
You may add a redirection as a app.config file to your test project, aiming the higher version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```